# Titles in JabRef are not being displayed correctly in the window

Tags: italic, jabref

today I actualized my JabRef version to 4.0. I have some titles with species that must be writed in italic. The old version showed it correctly, however, this new version not. Anyone know how can I solve it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, you have to use a Font which supports this, another user had the same problem on Mac and had to install a new font. https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/3270